# how to execute two maven version plugin?

Tags: java, maven, swagger

how to execute two maven version plugin? I try this but execute all in 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT

I have a problem because V2.x.x use a V2 swagger file and v3.0.0 use a V3 swagger file.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>first in v2</id>
            ...
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>second in v3</id>
            ...
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please add the errors that you see to your question.

Comment: I already write my problem: Maven execute all in 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT and not the first in 2.3.1 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Parent/module Maven feature.

**MyProject-parent**

```
<modules>
    <module>foodle-importer-core</module>
    <module>foodle-api</module>
    <module>diffusion-api</module>
</modules>
```

**architecture:**

```
MyProject-parent
       ---------ModuleA-SourceGeneratorV2 (contain swagger-codegen-maven-plugin v2.3.1)
       ---------ModuleB-SourceGeneratorV3 (contain swagger-codegen-maven-plugin v3.0.0-SNAPSHOT)
       ---------ModuleC-MyProject (contain `ModuleA-SourceGeneratorV2` and `ModuleB-SourceGeneratorV3` dependencies)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following

[Can Maven 2 use two different versions of a build plugin in the same project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909133/can-maven-2-use-two-different-versions-of-a-build-plugin-in-the-same-project)

it is not possible to do what you want to do. The only chance I see is to grab the source code and compile the plugin under a different name. Before you do that I would really look for another way to achieve what you want to achieve.